# How to configure Apache Shiro with Struts1.3 and tomcat7?

Tags: tomcat7, struts-1, shiro

We have Web Application which is running with Struts1.3 , Google-Guice and ApacheTomcat7.
Now I want to integrate security framework Apache shiro.

Following is my configuration in pom.xml for downloading dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Following is the Web.xml configuration(Filters & Listener):

```
 <listener>
     <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter</filter-class>

</filter>

<!-- Make sure any request you want accessible to Shiro is filtered. /* catches all -->
<!-- requests.  Usually this filter mapping is defined first (before all others) to -->
<!-- ensure that Shiro works in subsequent filters in the filter chain:             -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Following is my shiro.ini file configuration:
                [main]

```
            # specify login page
            authc.loginUrl = /welcome.do 
            # name of request parameter with username; if not present filter assumes 'username'
            authc.usernameParam = user
            # name of request parameter with password; if not present filter assumes 'password'
            authc.passwordParam = password


            # redirect after successful login
            authc.successUrl  = /Views/welcome.jsp



            # Let's use some in-memory caching to reduce the number of runtime lookups against Stormpath.
            # A real application might want to use a more robust caching solution (e.g. ehcache or a
            # distributed cache).  When using such caches, be aware of your cache TTL settings: too high
            # a TTL and the cache won't reflect any potential changes in Stormpath fast enough.  Too low
            # and the cache could evict too often, reducing performance.
            cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
            securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

            ds = com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
            ds.driverClass = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
            ds.jdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.87.54.2:1521:WAPD
            ds.username = USRIG395
            ds.password = changeme123
            # other BoneCP connection pool settings as desired

            jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
            jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds

            jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?"
            jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = "SELECT authority FROM user_roles WHERE username = ?"

            [urls]
            # enable authc filter for all application pages/**=authc



            [users]
            [roles]
            [urls]
             /** = authcBasic
```

After that when I start my tomcat it will give me following errors, it does not allow me to start my application:

```
            Apr 29, 2014 5:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
            SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener
            java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.shiro.web.util.WebUtils.normalize(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; from class org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.getServletContextResourceStream(IniWebEnvironment.java:280)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.convertPathToIni(IniWebEnvironment.java:249)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.createIni(IniWebEnvironment.java:163)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.getDefaultIni(IniWebEnvironment.java:134)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.init(IniWebEnvironment.java:82)
                at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:45)
                at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:40)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.createEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:221)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.initEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:133)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener.contextInitialized(EnvironmentLoaderListener.java:58)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
            Apr 29, 2014 5:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
            SEVERE: Error listenerStart
            ERROR - Shiro environment initialization failed
            java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.shiro.web.util.WebUtils.normalize(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; from class org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.getServletContextResourceStream(IniWebEnvironment.java:280)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.convertPathToIni(IniWebEnvironment.java:249)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.createIni(IniWebEnvironment.java:163)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.getDefaultIni(IniWebEnvironment.java:134)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.init(IniWebEnvironment.java:82)
                at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:45)
                at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:40)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.createEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:221)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.initEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:133)
                at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener.contextInitialized(EnvironmentLoaderListener.java:58)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is there any error in my configuration or any configuration misssing on my part? Please let me if I Missing something to describe in my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error almost always come from incompatible jars on the classpath.

You might have an old version of shiro-web.jar in your WEB-INF/lib folder or somewhere else in tomcat (the TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder for example).

Comment: Thanks, Its working for me . have two versions of jars are there. Thanks a ton.